# Confusing performance about two pieces of code with go goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

Here is a piece of code, the printed value of x is an indeterminate integer, eg:
*x = 359931570* , *x = 325604846*. The performance is expected.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
        var x int = 1
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
                go func() {
                        for {
                            x=add(x) // x=x+1 
                        }
                }()
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("end")
        fmt.Println("x =", x)
}

func add(x int) int {
  return x+1
}
```

But if I replace *x=add(x)* with *x=x+1* in the code, its output becomes always *x = 1*. It looks like the code in the goroutine is not executed. I can't understand this behavior, what is the explanation?

Comment: The code in your goroutine is not executed because you're not waiting for it to execute. Your `main` exits and that's it, the entire process is gone. In the other case you're simply lucky that scheduler decides to schedule the inner goroutine prior to continuing `main`. You can not really count on this sort of behavior in a real program and must rely on synchronization primitives, like channels and wait groups.

Answer (score 4):

The code has a data race, and the output is undefined. However, there is a way to explain why `x=1` at the end.

With multiple goroutines updating the shared variable `x` with no explicit synchronization, there are no guarantees that other goroutines will see the updates to the variable `x` made by one goroutine. Thus the Go memory model allows the case where the main goroutine never sees the effects of the other goroutines, and uses the initial value of `x`.

Why that changes when a function is used is interesting. But then, there is a data race and the output is undefined.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. And i would like to know why that changes when a function is used ?

Comment: the answer to that question is going to require a foray into the implementation details of Go.  It's undefined behavior - explanation is purely academic.  I would recommend you not waste your time *explaining* undefined behavior but instead just *avoid* it.

Comment: I can only guess. The crucial point here is that since there is a race, both behaviors are possible. It can be simply timing or pure luck.